# Python как удаленно отправить документ на печать?

Tags: python, print, corel-draw

Есть задача распечатать документ на принтер, который находится в другом помещении. Принтер можно подключить к приставке по USB. Вопрос в том, каким образом можно реализовать удаленную печать документа на Python? Подскажите библиотеку. Желательно независимую от формата документа, так как печать будет производиться в разных форматах, но в основном в векторных - CDR (CorelDraw). Нужно решение именно на Python, т.к. будет печать документа по названию из БД

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В этом поможет модуль `pycups` ([PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/pycups/)). Работа с ним предельно проста:

```
import cups
conn = cups.Connection ()
printers = conn.getPrinters ()
for printer in printers:
    conn.printFile(printer, filename, "Python_Status_print", {})
```

Также можно воспользоваться системными средствами и вызывать печать через модуль `subprocess`.

Comment: А как при этом послать сигнал на печать с сервера?

Comment: Я хочу понять, как можно с сервера отправить печать на удаленный пк?

Comment: Удалённая печать и печать на удалённом ПК - вообще-то разные вещи. Подключите принтер к своему ПК.